# How to attach a PDF file to a new email in Outlook and next move the file to a different folder?

Tags: batch-file

Ok I got it to work this way I wanted a solution that works for outlook.exe and thunderbird.exe can I use an IF EXISTS statement to differentiate between whether or not to use outlook or thunderbird.exe?  how do I scan only every 10 seconds so as to make this activity less resource intensive?

```
   :loop
    REM Example file 
    IF EXIST filename C:\Scanned\1.pdf GOTO command
    REM All this gets done if the file exists...
    :command 
    START outlook.exe /c /a C:\Scanned\1.pdf
    MOVE /Y C:\Scanned\1.pdf C:\Recieved
    ELSE
    GOTO LOOP
    :cont
```

like this?

```
:loop
REM Example file 
IF EXIST filename C:\Scanned\1.pdf 
GOTO command
ELSE
TIMEOUT /T 10
GOTO LOOP
REM All this gets done if the file exists...
:command
IF EXIST outlook.exe 
START /wait outlook.exe /c /a C:\Scanned\1.pdf
MOVE /Y C:\Scanned\1.pdf C:\Recieved
ELSE
GOTO
START /wait thunderbird.exe thunderbird -compose "attachment='$C:\Scanned\1.pdf'"
MOVE /Y C:\Scanned\1.pdf C:\Recieved
:cont
```

Comment: its throwing an error saying that DELETE and PASTE aren't valid commands yet some how COPY is...

Comment: Because PASTE isn't a valid command. DELETE is DEL instead. Yuu don't need PASTE; COPY does it all. `COPY <source> <dest>`. For any commands, use `help <command>` or `<command> /?` from the command line, as in `help copy` or `copy /?`. There's no way to attach a file to an email from the command prompt.

Comment: "copy" + "paste" + "delete" = `move`. See `move /?`. Also your `if`syntax is wrong. See `if /?`

Comment: Ive edited the script but it still is not getting me the results Im looking for

Comment: labels don't work that way. remove them, and instead add a label `:notexist` on its own line after the two commands, and change the if to `if not exist ... goto :notexist`. additionally, this loop is not a good idea, since it will run full speed all the time. maybe add a `timeout` command, depending on your needs.

Comment: to the call of thunderbird: i'm not sure how that can create a mail in outlook. in any case, you should call it with start /wait, because else your del will execute before thunderbird had any chance to do its thing.

Comment: You are right I added a 10 second delay but a strange thing occurs the compose window opens every 10 seconds but I thought that within my loop it is only called when a file exists within the path C:/Scanned but even if I remove the file from the path the outlook and or thunderbird executes over and over again am I missing the way  that IF ELSE statements work in Dos?

Comment: I keep getting ELSE is not an internal or external command do I require brackets like these >ELSE< ?

Comment: outlook commands 
   Compose outlook.exe /c
   Attach outlook.exe /a

Comment: concerning your "ELSE"-Problem: type `if /?` and read it's output. If you have any questions, read it once more.

Comment: I have read that Stephan and I still don't see how my code is syntactically different they have written 3 ways that you cant do an IF ELSE statement they never give you the proper syntax in a legible format.

Comment: instead of being rude just tell me since you are so intelligent Stephan how to fix my syntax.

Comment: It took you more time to suggest the obvious in a cynical manner than to address the above code snippet...If I were a betting man Id say that you dont even know.

Comment: see my answer - didn't want to be rude, just turning you into the right direction.  I'd say, you lost your bet.

Answer (score 1):

copied directly from `if /?`:

```
IF EXIST test.txt (
    del test.txt
) ELSE (
    echo test.txt fehlt
)
```

This ist the correct syntax.

Comment: I've tried using brackets the program wont even run let alone loop if I implement brackets.

Comment: MY windows tells me, it IS. And I can confirm, it's right. *After* this example, it states, that the *following* two examples don't work.

Comment: just saw your suggested edit. You have some quirks in it: 1.) use `if exist C:\Scanned\1.pdf (` instead of `if exist filename C:\Scanned\1.pdf(`. 2.) Use `) else (` instead of `)else(` (note the spaces). 3.) `if`/`else`/`else` won't work.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting frustrated with this because all of the information that I want is in there and its dogging me over some spaces or nomenclature...

Comment: yes, `cmd` is a bit too exact with spaces in it's syntax. One gets used to this.

Comment: So you can't have multiple IF statements in one batch file would it be wrong to reference other batch files within a batch file this seems sloppy to me and breakable...

Comment: of course you can have as many `if` statements as you want, but every `if` supports only one `else`. Don't read a batchfile as a program. It's only a list of commands. You should now be able to correct your program (except attaching a file to a email)

Comment: Stephan I know for a fact you can launch outlook using outlook.exe and then give it parameters /c for compose and /a for attach

Comment: I now only have 2 IF statements and each only has one ELSE statement and still no execution...just looping command line with no errors...

Comment: my thunderbird syntax wasnt right this is the correct one for thunder bird thunderbird.exe -compose attachment= C:\Scanned\1.pdf